# How make a Live status

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom-events

Currently, I doing a project by using a live stream API, I faced on an issue that to update my live status, live stream provider allows me retrieval the data of a number of views and live status, but it's is not a constant value, which is the value given would change anytime. Is that any method to update my live data interval, by using js PHP or jQuery, but not setInterval or setTimeout in js.

This is my PHP code (getBroadcastStatus.php)

```
<?php
use models\getLiveStatus;
spl_autoload_register(function($class_name){ include $class_name.".php";});
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

$getLiveStatus = new getLiveStatus();
$counter = rand(1, 10);
while (1) {
echo $getLiveStatus->getBroadcastStatus(); 
  $counter--;

  if (!$counter) {

    $counter = rand(1, 10);
  }

  ob_end_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
```

This is my js code follow the 
suggestion here:
 [How make a Live status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516958/how-make-a-live-status?noredirect=1#comment64430461_38516958)

Documentation here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

```
  var evtSource = new EventSource('getBroadcastStatus.php');
    evtSource.addEventListener('ping',function(e){
       alert(e.data);
    }}) ;
```

Comment: server sent events, except you're SOOL if you want to use IE

Comment: Can give more details?

Comment: read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events), write some code, and if your code doesn't work, ask why

Comment: `var evtSource = new EventSource('getBroadcastStatus.php');
        evtSource.addEventListener('ping',function(e){
            e.onmmessage = function(m){
                
                
            }
        }}) ; `
I added this to my file and the event listener cause error, is that I set wrong anything?

Comment: code in comments is pointless, you also seem to be mixing the two methods of using SSE's together for some reason

Comment: This is my php code.
`use models\getLiveStatus;
error_reporting(E_ALL^E_NOTICE);

$getLiveStatus = new getLiveStatus();
$counter = rand(1, 10);
while (1) {
echo $getLiveStatus->getBroadcastStatus(); 
  $counter--;
  
  if (!$counter) {

    $counter = rand(1, 10);
  }
  
  ob_end_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}`
This is my js code.
` var evtSource = new EventSource('getBroadcastStatus.php');
        evtSource.addEventListener('ping',function(e){
           alert(e.data);
        }}) ;   `

the event listener not running at all

Comment: right ... unreadable gibberish in a comment, are you able to edit your question and put the code in there to make it readable?